# Switching between modules dynamically in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I have a module in OCaml that is parameterized by another module, which represents a data structure (H = Hashtable, M = Map, L = LossyMap). I would now like to let this data structure be selected via the command line.

The way I create the main processing module is:

```
module HashSampler = MakeSampler(HashtableMatrix)
module MapSampler = MakeSampler(MapMatrix)

etc.
```

Unfortunately, the code that multiplexes between these is ugly:

```
match representation with
| "Hashtable" ->
       let matrix = HashSampler.create () in
           HashSampler.process_file matrix file
| "Map" -> 
       let matrix = MapSampler.create () in
           MapSampler.process_file matrix file
```

Is there a better way of doing this that somehow prevents code duplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use first class modules. Here's some example code that shows one possibility.

```
module type Sampler = sig
    type t
    val create : unit -> t
    val process_file : t -> string -> unit
end
module HashSampler : Sampler = struct
    type t = unit
    let create () = ()
    let process_file () file = ()
end
module MapSampler : Sampler = struct
    type t = unit
    let create () = ()
    let process_file () file = ()
end

let choose_sampler : string -> (module Sampler) = function
    | "Hashtable" -> (module HashSampler)
    | "Map" -> (module MapSampler)

let process representation file =
    let (module M) = choose_sampler representation in
    let matrix = M.create () in M.process_file matrix file
```